# Como criar uma função para ir para outra aba no IONIC?

Tags: ionic

Existe alguma função que permita eu ir para determinada aba de uma aplicação no ionic? Supondo que eu tenha essa organização de aba:

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-positive">

        <ion-tab title="Home" icon="ion-home" href="#/tab/home">
          <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <ion-tab title="About" icon="ion-ios-information" href="#/tab/about">
          <ion-nav-view name="about-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <ion-tab title="Contact" icon="ion-ios-world" ui-sref="tabs.contact">
          <ion-nav-view name="contact-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>
```

Comment: Você quis dizer "ir para outra view?"

Answer (score -1):

No seu `html` você usa:

```
(click)="home()" ao invés de href
```

Dentro do arquivo `.TS`

```
home (){
this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);

}
```